# How to change the raster cell values where they overlap with the cells of another raster?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, arcgis-10.3, spatial-analyst

I have a raster that I'm trying to edit by changing the value of select cells (those that overlap with the cells of another raster).

For some context, what I'm trying to do is create a Distance to Water layer (Euclidean distance) where the interior of water bodies is "NoData". This has all been derived from a watercourse polyline layer and a waterbody polygon layer. I'm using ArcGIS 10.3.1.

Below is a screenshot the two rasters I'm working with. The green is the waterbody layer, and I'm hoping to change the value of the cells in the Distance To layer that overlap to NoValue (or something else which I can later reclassify as NoValue).

[image]

Comment: Raster calculator Con(~IsNull("green"),"distance")